# Advice for build multiusers big website (1. scala lift/spring roo 2. database mongoDB/Postgre ORM/MySql ORM 3. Web-server environment Tomcat etc..)

Tags: scala, tomcat, spring-mvc, lift, spring-roo

I need advice for build multi-users big/huge website - I am the only programmer and the owner of this website, doing that in my free time + my money (meanwhile).

(I have few years of experience as Web Programmer(Lamp,Ubuntu, Zend, Mysql Doctrine ORM, Jquery) - I want to give try for JVM static type langs java spring roo/scala 
I know  Java + JSP+ Servlets + Beans but not Spring Roo/Spring MVC or Scala.
)

My Questions(Please answer according 1. stability of solution 2. price 3.time to program 4. time to study this technologies 5. etc..):

1. which lang/framework choose scala lift/spring roo - Important what more
2. Which database mongoDB/Postgre ORM/MySql ORM
3. Hosting (I thinking to take amazon  Ubuntu package)
4. Web-server environment to run website (I know lamp, but Java I dont know about servers (Tomcat for run java?,Apache for HTTP - please give me good option that will not cost me a lot money, prefer free and stable)) - I saw Cloud Foundry - really cool, but its beta version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you have indicated that you are an experienced developer you should probably go with the technology you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of presentations on why Foursquare chose Lift:

https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dcbpz3ck_24f3v83ggz
http://www.vimeo.com/8057986

Keep in mind that at the time of the presentations, Foursquare had 1 full time engineer (Harry the guy giving the presentation) and nearly 1M users.

Foursquare has been able to securely scale with Lift and MongoDB.
See this comment about Foursquare's security: http://twitter.com/#!/rasmus/status/5929904263

And of course, Foursquare put Lift in space

The folks at http://openstudy.com have a tremendously cool real-time multiplay online learning site.  They have done it with 1 full time engineer and a couple of interns.

The folks at http://vibe.novell.com have built a very powerful, scalable system on Lift (although they have a fair number of engineers working on the project.)

Answer (score 1):

1. In my experience, Spring Roo is good for rapidly building a CRUD application and to set up a project (so, you don't have to write all that xml config stuff for spring, it will be generated by Roo for you). In comparison, Lift is a full stack web framework and scala a more feature-rich language than Java. Here I would prefer Scala and Lift. Altough both have a steep learning curve.
2. Depends on your data model. ;-)
3. Not enough information about that.
4. Here I you can choose any webcontainer you want (Tomcat, Jetty).

Comment: What do you think about play framework vs Lift?

Comment: As I've heard so far the play framework doesn't builds upon Java Servlets like Lift does. Play uses Groovy for Templating where Lift uses pure XHTML in comparison, which prevents you from tight coupled and ugly jsp-like templates (remember, the bad old times ^^). In general, Lift expresses another way of building your application. Play is more like a Ruby on Rails for Java with Scala support. ;-) For sure, there are a lot more differences. What's your point of view on this?

Comment: play framework not need to compile like other java/scala frameworks in process of programming- this should be very big advantage.

Comment: Well, if you use JRebel you have an equal feature: incremental hot deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think in you case the best choose [play framework](http://www.playframework.org/)